# Axios sending cookies for subdomain as well

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios

I have created an application and hosted on dev & production. This how the urls looks like `app.hello.com`, `app.dev.hello.com`. My server sending cookies and set cookie domain to `hello.com`, and `dev.hello.com`. All cookies set to `HTTPOnly` and `Secure: true`, `Samesite:Lax`.

I am using axios, and set `withCredentials:true` to read the cookies and send it in request headers.

- When I open `app.hello.com` only cookies with `hello.com` is sent to server.
- When I open `app.dev.hello.com` then all the cookies has either `hello.com`, or `dev.hello.com` sent to server. I need to restrict this to only `dev.hello.com`.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes: _"Setting the domain will make the cookie available to it, as well as to all its subdomains. If omitted, this attribute defaults to the host of the current document URL, not including subdomains."_